# How to migrate Fedora Directory Server

Tags: ldap, centos7, fedora, samba4, 389-ds

I am trying to migrate an old Fedora Core 8 machine to CentOS 7. It runs Samba and Fedora Directory server. It is used for authenticating Windows users. I would like to move to Samba4. What is the best way to do this?

I have tried exporting userRoot and NetscapeRoot with db2ldif from the old instance and then importing them into a new 389-ds-base install on the new system. However, nothing seems to happen when I try importing:

```
[root@localhost ~]# ldif2db -n userRoot -i /tmp/master-fds-vm-userRoot-2019_09_24_143444.ldif -V
importing data ...
[02/Oct/2019:13:10:29.522831117 +1300] - INFO - ldbm_instance_config_cachememsize_set - force a minimal value 512000
[02/Oct/2019:13:10:29.586587024 +1300] - INFO - dblayer_instance_start - Import is running with nsslapd-db-private-import-mem on; No other process is allowed to access the database
[02/Oct/2019:13:10:29.597389252 +1300] - INFO - check_and_set_import_cache - pagesize: 4096, available bytes 1218830336, process usage 22802432
[02/Oct/2019:13:10:29.606072307 +1300] - INFO - check_and_set_import_cache - Import allocates 476105KB import cache.
[02/Oct/2019:13:10:29.764355975 +1300] - INFO - import_main_offline - import userRoot: Beginning import job...
[02/Oct/2019:13:10:29.773533042 +1300] - INFO - import_main_offline - import userRoot: Index buffering enabled with bucket size 100
[02/Oct/2019:13:10:29.979991685 +1300] - INFO - import_producer - import userRoot: Processing file "/tmp/master-fds-vm-userRoot-2019_09_24_143444.ldif"
[02/Oct/2019:13:10:30.267741538 +1300] - INFO - import_producer - import userRoot: Finished scanning file "/tmp/master-fds-vm-userRoot-2019_09_24_143444.ldif" (0 entries)
[02/Oct/2019:13:10:30.285382560 +1300] - INFO - import_monitor_threads - import userRoot: Workers finished; cleaning up...
[02/Oct/2019:13:10:30.390121280 +1300] - INFO - import_monitor_threads - import userRoot: Workers cleaned up.
[02/Oct/2019:13:10:30.400309535 +1300] - INFO - import_main_offline - import userRoot: Cleaning up producer thread...
[02/Oct/2019:13:10:30.405254121 +1300] - INFO - import_main_offline - import userRoot: Indexing complete.  Post-processing...
[02/Oct/2019:13:10:30.409632455 +1300] - INFO - import_main_offline - import userRoot: Generating numsubordinates (this may take several minutes to complete)...
[02/Oct/2019:13:10:30.418819816 +1300] - INFO - import_main_offline - import userRoot: Generating numSubordinates complete.
[02/Oct/2019:13:10:30.423092666 +1300] - INFO - ldbm_get_nonleaf_ids - import userRoot: Gathering ancestorid non-leaf IDs...
[02/Oct/2019:13:10:30.426980126 +1300] - INFO - ldbm_get_nonleaf_ids - import userRoot: Finished gathering ancestorid non-leaf IDs.
[02/Oct/2019:13:10:30.434793064 +1300] - ERR - ldbm_ancestorid_new_idl_create_index - Nothing to do to build ancestorid index
[02/Oct/2019:13:10:30.439823864 +1300] - INFO - ldbm_ancestorid_new_idl_create_index - import userRoot: Created ancestorid index (new idl).
[02/Oct/2019:13:10:30.444923191 +1300] - INFO - import_main_offline - import userRoot: Flushing caches...
[02/Oct/2019:13:10:30.449721205 +1300] - INFO - import_main_offline - import userRoot: Closing files...
[02/Oct/2019:13:10:30.458245882 +1300] - INFO - dblayer_pre_close - All database threads now stopped
[02/Oct/2019:13:10:30.462837420 +1300] - INFO - import_main_offline - import userRoot: Import complete.  Processed 0 entries in 1 seconds. (0.00 entries/sec)
```

How do I find out what schemas, etc are required?

Comment: Being much more specific about what problem you see is more informative than "doesn't work".

Comment: I've added some log output from when I tried to import the LDIF file.

Answer (score 0):

389 documentation on the basics like upgrading is rather sparse, as they defer to Red Hat Directory Server. Which on a different version number.  Even with all the confusion, the Red Hat DS docs regarding upgrading from the early versions (7?) may be useful.

Regarding schemas, [pre-migration tasks includes copying over the schema files](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_directory_server/10/html/installation_guide/pre-migration_tasks#Schema_Migration).

If you had an existing install, `yum upgrade`  and `setup-ds-admin.pl -u` [should be sufficient](http://www.port389.org/docs/389ds/legacy/install-guide.html#upgrading). However, the differences between Fedora DS on Fedora 8 to 389 on CentOS 7 are large. Export and import should be the most compatible option that can handle the version differences. Replicating probably isn't an option for this upgrade.